# Apache solr is not accessible by my server but accessible by my localhost

Tags: search

I have a solr installed in my server(centos 6.5).and everything works fine and my conf files exist where they should be. I try to connect to solr by help of [search_api_solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) module in drupal. Everything works fine on my localhost and one other host I try my website on,but when I try to connect to this solr using a website on the same server as the solr I'm get error

> The Solr server could not be reached

where should I start looking for something that went wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be more about server configuration and it's iptables (or equivalent) than about Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was caused by selinux on my server.

by disabling selinux and rebooting centOs I could connect to my solr apache.

I found the answer **[here](https://www.drupal.org/node/436840#comment-2432720)**